Installing m4 on ubuntu 24.04 returns a gcc error
I'm trying to install the package m4 as per the ubuntu repositories by running
sudo apt-get install m4
But the command returns this error
Setting up install-info (7.1-3build2) ...
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
dpkg: error processing package install-info (--configure):
 installed install-info package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 install-info
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Any suggestion on how to fix this error?

That's pretty weird - so far as I can tell, all that the install-info.postinst script does is invoke the (newly installed) update-info-dir script. The only way I can see gcc being involved is if that script got modified somehow or if you have a different executable program or script named update-info-dir earlier in your sudoers secure_path

Might this be a problem with related packages? e.g. gcc --version, or even a better option / missing $ sudo apt install build-essential ?

@Hannu If the error is gcc: fatal error: no input files then gcc is already installed, but the postinstall script does not provide necessary input files to gcc.

gcc itself, yes, but failure to provide input might be due to the missing parameters (filenames?) could not be "generated" (e.g. by a makefile entry). Reading Mutewinter's answer below, revealed a plausible cause - somewhat in line with this.

I seem to have understood what was causing the issue.
On this specific ubuntu machine I was trying to install the WRF weather model which requires setting some environmental variables.
Following the software guide and some Googling I added to my /etc/environment
CC= gcc
CXX = g++
FC = gfortran
FCFLAGS = -m64
F77 = gfortran
FFLAGS = -m64
DIR = "/home/wrf/Software/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES"
JASPERLIB = "$DIR/grib2/lib"
JASPERINC = "$DIR/grib2/include"
LDFLAGS = "-L$DIR/grib2/lib"
CPPFLAGS = "-I$DIR/grib2/include"

But apparently this throws off the installation process of any package (not just m4).
By commenting out these variables the installation works fine.
Now I have a second question: how can I set these variables without causing the installation issue?

/etc/environment is not a shell script - its entries should be simple KEY=VALUE pairs (without whitespace around the = ; iirc some versions of pam_env handled whitespace but it's not guaranteed) and AFAIK it does not support variable expansions like $DIR.

@steeldriver, thanks! At the moment I solved by moving everything in .bashrc

... so you appear to have discovered a potential code injection vulnerability whereby a malformed line like VAR= somecommand in /etc/environment causes a dpkg postinst script to execute somecommand - this deserves investigation imho

@steeldriver, I didn't think about that. Is there an official Ubuntu space where to notify things like that?

OK so I've done a bit more debugging and it seems like the mechanism is that the install-info.postinst shell script invokes update-info-dir, and /usr/sbin/update-info-dir (also a shell script) sources /etc/environment. So a malformed line like CC= gcc there causes the shell to execute gcc with CC set to the empty string.
